# types of questions in exams

Tags: word-request

There are practice or practical questions and what's the name for the other type of questions that have to do with memorizing? And is it practical questions or practice questions?

Comment: A _practical_ test is one that requires you do do something rather than give an answer in words. A _practice_ question would be one you answer before the exam to see how well-prepared you are. I don't know what you mean by 'the other type'.

Comment: Additional to Kate: Tests can concern **practice** (doing something) and/or **theory** (understanding/explaining something).

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean *practical* and *theory*, although these are two types of *assessment*, not really types of 'question'.

A practical examination would be one where you actually perform a task under test conditions - such as baking a cake for a cookery qualification. A 'theory' test would be a written (or possibly oral) examination where you answer questions from memory.

Written exams can contain different types of question, such as multiple-choice questions, answering true or false, or writing an essay.

Note also that there are two different meanings of "practice", one of which is related to the word "practical". *Putting something into practice* means applying the theory you know - for example, you might read a recipe for a cake (theory) and then make the cake (putting the theory into practice). *Practical examinations* are a demonstration that you can put theory into practice. The other meaning of "practice" is to repeatedly *rehearse* something in order to improve at it or gain a skill. The term "practice examination" could therefore be taken to mean a sample, or rehearsal examination prior to the real thing in order to give students the experience of exam conditions - such exams are usually called 'mock' exams in British English.

Comment: But I can say: "will this exam be theoretical?" or "will the exam have theoretical questions", can't I?